# Installing Debian drivers in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, debian, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

I have Nvidia driver 460.80 installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. I've bought myself a RTX 3080 Ti and now my Ubuntu wouldn't boot (I can only go into recovery console). 3080 Ti requires Nvidia driver version 460.84, which isn't officially available via Ubuntu yet but I've found a [.deb](https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-nonfree-amd64/nvidia-driver_460.84-1_amd64.deb.html) for it. So before I do anything stupid, can I install a Debian driver on Ubuntu?

Comment: Debian *sid* means it's for a 5.10 *testing* kernel, which is not a kernel used by Ubuntu (20.04.3 with HWE will use the 5.11 kernel in the future, but not 5.10).   Drivers are actually *kernel modules* so relate to the kernel in use; and Ubuntu does **not** use Debian kernels so if you use it, you could be expecting problems (it's a *testing* grade Debian kernel too, not what Debian deem as *stable*)

Comment: (correction to my last comment, Ubuntu does have *supported* 5.10 OEM kernels; it's not a *generic* supported kernel...) *also don't forget the "Requires" section, you'll need those too, and have to check the packages match, and don't have more requires, or conflicts etc*

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping of installing through `apt` and keep everything in the package manager. I ended up downloading directly from Nvidia and running the script